# Price or Currency becomes 0.00

Tags: php, mysql

I tried looking for the simplest and easy to understand solution for this but can't get that perfect description to search in google.

I have a MySQL database and one of the columns there is a Decimal type (10,2) and it is prepared for Price column.

When I do INSERT INTO TABE Mysql query in PHP, it doesn't give any errors but the value becomes 0.00 instead of the $25,000

Do I need to manually replace or remove the $ and , signs so MySQL accepts these prices correctly?

Comment: Decimal separator should be dot, not comma, and you shouldn't include the currency symbol.

Comment: `$` is varchar not decimal. Decimal fields will not accepts characters

Comment: To be perfectly sure, can you share the query you used?

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't post a decimal separator though, that's a comma because that's a thousand separator :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DECIMAL` SQL column should only contain numbers and optionally a decimal separator. So you should definitely **not** have the currency symbol, and should use the `.` (period) decimal symbol.

If it doesn't work with a `.` separator it is possible that your locale settings prefer the `,` decimal separator and the `.` for thousands separator.

Any time a value like that defaults to `0.00` it means it couldn't parse the given value to anything that makes sense for a decimal field.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess I have to replace the characters like `$` and `,` before inserting to MySQL

Comment: @jay Yes, the currency symbols ($, €, etc) and the thousands separators. Anything other than the numbers and the decimal separator are just "decoration" to make it more readable, but your database doesn't need that.